# Umbraco Navigation - Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I have a True/False editor in my page doc type and I am using if to create the site navigation.

If topNavigation Checkbox is checked display item in the navigation

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    var root = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().First();
    var nodes = root.Children.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue("topNavigation") != "True");

}


  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @foreach (var page in nodes)
        {
        <p>@page.GetPropertyValue("topNavigation")</p>
        <li class="@(page.IsAncestorOrSelf(Model.Content) ? "current" : null)">
            <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
        </li>
        }
    </ul>
@*}*@
```

I can't seem to compare against a true value.

This shows everything -

```
var nodes = root.Children.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue("topNavigation") != "True");
```

..and this show nothing

```
var nodes = root.Children.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue("topNavigation") == "True");
```

Even though the checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should able to use `GetPropertyValue<bool>`

```
var root = Umbraco.TypedContentAtRoot().First();
var nodes = root.Children.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("topNavigation"));
```

Comment: Thank you - That worked. So does that always return true?

Comment: @KlydeMonroe it returns true or false regarding the settings in Umbraco from "topNavigation" property. By using GetPropertyValue<bool>, you specify that the property "topNavigation" is a bool.